# how to disable this clickable module after clicking once.....that button should remain disabled after refreshing tha page

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<a href="oaccept1.php?id=<?php echo $data['oaid'];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary login-submit-cs" 
onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure')">ACCEPT</a>
```

[image: this is the button 'm talkin' about]

want to disable that button after accepting that and it should stay disabled after accepting that doc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+disable+after+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

Use server side, don't depend on only javascript

In table add new field as `accepted` and make it false by default,

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_name` ADD `accepted` BOOLEAN default false;
```

on click of accept button event function, set this field as true

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`(id, accepted) VALUES ('2',true );
```

Then in your php have

```
<?php  if($data['accepted']==false){?>
  <a href="oaccept1.php?id=<?php echo $data['oaid'];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-
     primary login-submit-cs" 
     onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure')">
     ACCEPT
  </a>

<?php }else {?>

 <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-
     primary login-submit-cs" 
     disabled>
     ACCEPT
  </a>
<?php }?>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Good idea if possible

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make it a button, otherwise a simple visit from a google bot will accept all

Alternative is to use a form submit event

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const sub = document.querySelector(".login-submit-cs");
  const dis = false; //  localStorage.getItem("submitted"); // remove "false; //" to activate
  if (!dis) sub.removeAttribute("disabled");
  sub.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let  tgt = e.target.closest("button"); // using closest in case the element has children
    if (!tgt || dis) return; // not the link
    setTimeout(() => tgt.setAttribute("disabled","disabled"),200); // allow the button to be pressed
    // localStorage.setItem("submitted",true); // remove comment lines to activate
    location = tgt.dataset.href;
  });
});
```

```html
<button data-href="oaccept1.php?id=<?php echo $data['oaid'];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary login-submit-cs" disabled>ACCEPT</button>
```